# Report with tcodes utilization on per user & per date basis

Tags: abap, sap-basis

We want to create a report with Select Criteria DATE & USER and we display the Transactions that run per user & per date.

I know the transaction **ST03N** but it does not extract the data as I want (DATE-USER-TCODES).

Does anyone know where to find these data, which tables?

Thanks in advance
Elias

Answer (score 2):

Everything is in ST03N:

1. Select target system from the list in the very top menu
2. Expand the list of periods (day, month, total) and select the necessary leaf in the necessary node

[image]

3. After **double-click** (important!) on that leaf the window will appear in the bottom-left corner. In that window one can choose the necessary stats.
   Here we need to select *User and Settlement Statistics* and *User Profile* below.
4. After **double-click** on the necessary stat, windows in the right will be filled with data.
5. Here we need to double-click again on the target user and all his tcodes on the selected date will be displayed in the popup.

[image]

P.S. If you miss *User and Settlements Statistics* node in your system, then some of the [Performance Collectors](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw74/helpdata/en/84/9e0e422dfcdc2ce10000000a1550b0/frameset.htm) are not set up properly on your system.

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer. But as you can understand this is not useful for business. Their question is how the can have in a screen per date-user the tcodes? It is not proper to go to each user and double click in order to see what tcodes used. They want to give the period and for all users or some of them to be displayd in the screen or downloaded in a file.  Anyway thanks for your detail answer again.

Comment: Use [CCMS](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/c4/3a5dba505211d189550000e829fbbd/frameset.htm) and/or [SolMan](https://blogs.sap.com/2009/02/20/sap-solution-manager-overview-for-dummies/) for that. It is a BASIS task to generate such type of reporting, not end-user task.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to get this from one specific table; however, you can use the following function module to fetch the information:

`SWNC_COLLECTOR_GET_AGGREGATES`

You will have to pass the following parameters:

```
IMHOSTNAME                                      "HOSTNAME"
IMDATUM                                         "DATE"
IMPERITYPE                                      "D/W/M"
```

Variable `EX_DATA-APPLICATION_STAT` will have all the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, you want to display, what a specific user did in the system on a given day? If yes, have a look at transaction STAD.

Comment: It's not usefull. My question is **from which tables gathers these data**?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The table that stores all data from ST03N is MONI, however it is encoded and cannot be read. You will have to write a custom program using SWNC_COLLECTOR_GET_AGGREGATES function module or check out ones already available online.